# Commutability and order of active record scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is the place of the "sorting" "filters" (Desc or Asc) inside a Rails' Active Record query important in terms of performance and logic ?

For example is the following scope 1 the sam as scope 2

**SCOPE 1**

```
scope :default_stream, -> { order(deal_end_date: :asc) } # this is the "sorting query"
scope :scope_1,
      lambda { default_stream.where('deal_start_date <= ? AND deal_end_date >= ?', Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now).where(is_cool: true) }
```

**SCOPE 2**

```
scope :scope_2,
      lambda { Deal.all.where('deal_start_date <= ? AND deal_end_date >= ?', Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now).where(is_cool: true).order(deal_end_date: :asc) }
```

Should I first use the "sorting query" then the other filters (scope1) or the opposite (scope2) ?

Not sure if it has an impact, but let me that the number of deals can be very important (>100000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Your scopes aren't actually evaluated until the point in time when you try to read the results. `order` and `where` clauses can be appended to your relation in any order, as they get placed in the same place in the final SQL query.

When in doubt, try both ways and invoke `.to_sql` on your scopes. You'll find that `scope1.to_sql` is identical to `scope2.to_sql`.

Given a simple `Post` model, you'll find that `Post.order(:name).where(active: true)` and `Post.where(active: true).order(:name)` product **identical** SQL:

```
select * from posts where active = true order by name
```

Neither the `order` or the `where` happen "first", that's impossible. There is only one SQL query generated, and the all its various clauses (where, order, limit, offset etc) go where they need to go to produce a syntactically valid query.

Comment: so putting first the non sorting query (where('deal_..... Time.zone.now).where(is_cool: true)) would not be faster? I thought that because it would output a limited/smaller number of lines then the sorting query (order(deal_end_date: :asc) as a second step would be faster than sorting the whole database lines...  you're saying that in fact in the resulting sql, it's automatically optimized for this by active record?

Comment: @Mathieu That isn't at all how that works. `.order(foo).where(bar)` and `.where(foo).order(bar)` will do the **exact same thing**. They will produce the *same* SQL and the *same* records. The ordering/filtering is done in by the database, not by Ruby. Neither `order` or `where` happens "first"; Rails takes all of them (no matter what order you called them in) and turns them into **one** SQL query.

Comment: ok i see, will check .to_sql in doubt:). thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction